# How does lock work in parallel programing?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I’m studying for my exam and I came across this question asking the potential output of the following code.I’m confused why when having used .lock(), the other running thread can still compete for resources with the “locked” thread.

```
void print(char c); // output character c
std::mutex m; // global variable useable by all threads

void A(){
    m.lock();
    print(’A’);
    print(’B’);
    m.unlock();
}

void B(){
    print(’C’);
    std::thread t(A);
    print(’D’);
    t.join();
}

int main(){
    std::thread t(B);
    t.join();
}
```

I think due to the use of lock, the expected output should only be ‘CABD’,but the answer is ‘CABD’,‘CDAB’ and ‘CADB’. Could you please explain, thanks.

Comment: The mutex protects nothing in this case. A is only called once anyway.

Comment: Lock does not "lock" thread, it will only wait if mutex is already locked somewhere else. Since thread `A` is the only thread that tries to lock the mutex locking it won't provide any synchronization.

Comment: @KamilCuk Just curious, why would buffering change the output result?

Answer (score 4):

> I’m confused why when having used .lock(), the other running thread can still compete for resources with the “locked” thread.

Indeed, you are confused. There is no such thing as "locked thread", or at least it means something else. Lock is a synchronization object. When two threads try to call `m.lock();` on **the same** `std::mutex m;` object then one of them will suceed and acquire the lock, while the other will wait until the lock is released. Thus `m.lock();` is the synchronization point and **all threads have to hit the same synchronization point** for any locking to work.

So in your code only `void A()` function acquires and releases the lock. Therefore for the synchronization to happen this function has to be called from multiple threads. But you create two threads: one in `main` that calls `void B()` and one in `void B()` that calls `void A()`. So all in all we have 3 threads (including the main thread) but only one of them calls `void A()`. So there's no synchronization at all.

Therefore the first thing that will happen is (print) `C` then `A B D` in any order under the constraint that `B` has to happen after `A` (because it is forced by `void A()`, btw, I strongly advice using less confusing naming). And so possible results are as you've described.

That's of course under the assumption that `void print(char c);` is thread safe, because if it is not then you are doomed, anything can happen: segfault (if you are lucky), system crash, correct result, incorrect result, a black hole eating earth, me loosing weight, anything. In such situations you cannot even call `print` without synchronization.

**Side note:** you may want to use [std::lock_guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) instead of manual locking and unlocking. Your code is not exception safe at the moment, unless `print` doesn't throw. Anyway manual (un)locking is a bad practice.

Comment: It is also worth noting that `std::thread(X)` gives no guarantees as to when `X()` will be executed.  It may be executed before `std::thread()` returns, or it may be executed a long time afterwards. (At the following `join()`.)

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding how a mutex works. A mutex only protects a region of code within its `lock()` and `unlock()` so it only protects `A()`. Multiple calls to `A()` in multiple threads would show you this.

Let's see your code in action:

```
Main thread:                               | Thread t(B):
// create a new thread and run `B()` on it.|
std::thread t(B);                          |
/* wait for the new thread to finish */    | //Come alive.
t.join();                                  | //print 'C'.
                                           | print('C');
                                           | //start a new thread t(A)
                                           | std::thread t(A);
                                           | //print 'D'
                                           | print('D');
                                           | t.join(); //wait for thread t(B) to finish.
```

Now our output will look like `C` because `t(B)` just printed `C` and nothing could've been printed before that. Let's show what `t(A)` is going to do:

```
Thread t(A):

//lock our global mutex `m`.
m.lock();
// print 'A'
print('A');
// print 'B'
print('B');
//unlock our global mutex `m`.
m.unlock();
```

Since nobody is holding the current mutex `m` we can take it right away, lock it, and continue with our code.

The difference in output comes from the fact that `std::thread` doesn't always immediately run whenever you create an object from it. A lot of factors come into play when it comes to thread scheduling so that's for another answer. This does give us wiggle room when it comes to seeing our outputs. Let's match `t(B)` and `t(A)` together the moment `t(A)`'s thread spawns:

```
Thread t(B):                  |  Thread t(A):
/*start a new thread t(A)*/   |
std::thread t(A);             |  //come alive.
```

From this point onwards, the following things can happen:

- Thread `t(A)` is spawned and starts but `t(B)` is faster and prints `D` before `t(A)` has a chance to print `A` or `B`.

Or

- Thread `t(A)` is spawned and starts, it is faster than `t(B)` and prints out `A` and `B`, then `t(B)` prints out `D`.

Or

- Thread `t(A)` is spawned and starts, it is faster than `t(B)` and prints out `A` but then `t(B)` catches up and prints out `D` before `t(B)` can print out `B`.

This means that the combinations you're seeing are all valid. Your mutex is doing nothing to stop Thread `t(B)` from printing out `D` before Thread `t(A)` can even begin to print.

To make use of your mutex and see it in action, try spawning 2 threads that call `A`:

```
print(’C’);
std::thread t(A);
std::thread t2(A);
print(’D’);
t.join();
t2.join();
```

Now one of the threads has to wait on the other for the mutex to unlock before being allowed inside the locked area.

This means that both of these threads can run as follows:

```
t(A):             |    t2(A):
                  |
                  |
/*takes lock.*/   |
m.lock();         |   /*tries to take lock but fails because t(A) already holds it and thus has to wait*/
                  |  m.lock();
print('A');       |  //..still waiting..
print(’B’);       |  // zzz..
m.unlock();       |  //now that the mutex is free we can lock() and print!
//done            |  // print A & B and unlock mutex..
```

This can also happen the other way around, t2 taking the mutex before t and thus it printing before t2.

Due to the mutex you will always see `ABAB` as a result and can never see `ABBA` or `AABB` because the two threads can not be in the critical mutex section at the same time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. So does it mean that in your example, all possible outputs are CABABD, CABDAB, CDABAB?

Comment: @DominicDong Correct!